# Post data missing characters in base64

Tags: c#, post, base64

I am trying to send a post to my php script from a C# application but the `base64_decode()` keeps failing.

This is the string my post is trying to send:

> stWC3F34AboxsfjbxAWtGU8WUHIombDMd6Z4WXxyOae0+NlISFHVEATxjE8EFKKMkDnQe0oFu8AvQM9lRaSSMgjYnyZvhXB8EiQDImgrsTmgvwsIeu4qZiW2O6cK4oaPUJIIFnEDlNCstc4s1mzseq0zv0xYPy3tRqbWPXVV9jv9BZiMFGxeVD+OKV/mO0NkVP4UVUMcFOXVCKh5HslVZv59lEqa5C230HSyv17/W0G1e7q4tBxWEhUwCfbldNtk

and when the script receives it the "+" are replaced with " " so i use str_replace() to readd them and then pass the output to base64_decode() but it keeps returning false.

This is the string that gets passed to `base64_decode()` BEFORE replacing the " " with "+"

> stWC3F34AboxsfjbxAWtGU8WUHIombDMd6Z4WXxyOae0 NlISFHVEATxjE8EFKKMkDnQe0oFu8AvQM9lRaSSMgjYnyZvhXB8EiQDImgrsTmgvwsIeu4qZiW2O6cK4oaPUJIIFnEDlNCstc4s1mzseq0zv0xYPy3tRqbWPXVV9jv9BZiMFGxeVD OKV/mO0NkVP4UVUMcFOXVCKh5HslVZv59lEqa5C230HSyv17/W0G1e7q4tBxWEhUwCfbldNtk

This is the string that gets passed to `base64_decode()` AFTER replacing the " " with "+"

> stWC3F34AboxsfjbxAWtGU8WUHIombDMd6Z4WXxyOae0+NlISFHVEATxjE8EFKKMkDnQe0oFu8AvQM9lRaSSMgjYnyZvhXB8EiQDImgrsTmgvwsIeu4qZiW2O6cK4oaPUJIIFnEDlNCstc4s1mzseq0zv0xYPy3tRqbWPXVV9jv9BZiMFGxeVD+OKV/mO0NkVP4UVUMcFOXVCKh5HslVZv59lEqa5C230HSyv17/W0G1e7q4tBxWEhUwCfbldNtk

And from what I read the only reason why it should return false is if the string contains characters from outside the base64 alphabet, but it appears to be a valid base64 string.

Any help is appreciated. If I can't get this fixed I'll just start posting hex strings instead of base64.

Comment: Have you tried to copy and paste the C# output to the PHP bypassing the network to see if the generate base64 strings are decodable?

Comment: i just tried copy pasting my string directly into the function and it still fails.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing a URLEncode on the string before you send it? That should fix the problem with the plus sign.

Comment: No i am not. What do i have to include in order to use it? is it somewhere in System.Web?

Comment: Try the WebUtility class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.aspx

Comment: ...or just send it as POST-data and not in the URL... URL encoding is specific to, well, the URL :-)

Answer (score 2):

You also need to replace any slash characters (`/`), which represents the value 63 in standard base64 encoding. The common usage is to convert `+` to `-`, and `/` to `_`.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications

In addition, some base64 decoders require that the string be padded with `=` characters so that the string's length is a multiple of 3. I don't know if PHP's `base64_decode` requires this. See the linked Wikipedia article for information about the padding.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `urlencode` in php and `HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode` in C#

EDIT: Sorry, what you want is the other way round:

`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` in c# and `urldecode` in php